# For Docker, how to access LAN hosts, and also other containers at the same time?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am making a new project which contains a NodeJS service and a MySQL server with Docker-Compose. The NodeJS service needs to find data from the old MSSQL server just in case the data does not exist on the new MySQL server. The MSSQL server is located somewhere 192.168.0.x. May I know how to make both Docker-internal network work as well as the "host" network?

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: pos-db
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
  server:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile.dev
      context: ./
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command: ['./docker/wait-for-it.sh', 'mysql:3306', '--', 'yarn', 'watch']
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  pos-db:
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617673/how-do-i-connect-containers-in-different-networks-in-docker-compose check if this helps you

Comment: @Nobody Thanks for your reply. It is not exactly my problem. Since the old MSSQL server is not within the docker service stack. The MSSQL is a standalone server located at 192.168.0.x. So I need the "server" container to connect to the "host network" and the "docker network" at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried `network_mode: "host"` in your server container?

Comment: @VishakhaLall Yes. Connection to MSSQL works, but not MySQL. I want both of them to work.

Comment: You don't need to do anything at all, you should be able to reach both local containers and remote services without any special setup.  Do you have a specific example of a setup that doesn't work, including an error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add an `extra_hosts` section to your `server` service. Check the official documentation at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts

Example:

```
  server:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile.dev
      context: ./
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command: ['./docker/wait-for-it.sh', 'mysql:3306', '--', 'yarn', 'watch']
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    extra_hosts:
      - "mssqlhost:192.168.0.x"
```

Then you can reference your MSSQL server from your dockerized application using the name `mssqlhost`

Comment: According to the link, "An entry with the ip address and hostname is created in /etc/hosts inside containers for this service". Without special routing, "192.168.0.x" should not work, right? I think this method only works for public IP addresses.

Comment: if your host sees that IP then so will your container

Comment: From "docker-compose logs -f", I have got "message: 'Failed to connect to mssqlhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)'... code: 'ESOCKET'". The host can connect to the MSSQL server.

Comment: PING mssqlhost (192.168.0.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 56f2ed5b49e8 (192.168.0.3) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: "docker-compose down", removed everything (volumes, network, etc), "docker-compose up --build", the MSSQL server could be ping-ed. Thank you very much! (And I did not know extra_hosts before)